# TFS Visual studio 2010, I do not see Merge Changes in Merge Tool Option for some types. How can I enable it?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

when there is confilct on merging, merge tool option is not avaliable for some files, while it is avliable for other page type. check two screen shot below

[Merge Changes in merge tool is not avaliable for aspx page type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8AMM.png)

[merge changes in merge tool is avaliable for sln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8h2V.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just enable the option "`Enable file merging and multiple check-out`" for the file type  `*.aspx`.

For example in VS 2015 (*no vs 2010 on my side, it should be similar as vs 2015*):

1. Open Visual Studio --> Connect to your TFS server
2. `Team` --> `Team Project Collection Settings` --> `Source Control...`
3. Select the `Asp.net Files` --> `Edit`
4. Make sure the file type `*.aspx` is added and the option "`Enable file merging and multiple check-out`" is enabled/checked
5. Close and **restart** the Visual Studio, then try it again, the `Merge Changes in Merge Tool` option will show up now.

[image]